# Parsing XML data in an Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, osmdroid

I am trying to parse XML data for my app in Android Studio. My app constantly throws the "XmlPullParserException e" and writes "xml_error". I cant figure out why it is doing it.

The goal is to to get a List, that will only contain the place_id, longitude and latitude from the XML document.

I am fairly new to this, so I used a lot of the example code on the Android Developers website and rewrote it for my own purposes. I hope you can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

While debugging, I got more information about the error. But I dont know what to do with this information:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: 
START_TAG {null}searchresults (position:START_TAG (empty) 
<place place_id='129799074' osm_type='way' osm_id='220625788' place_rank='30' 
boundingbox='51.4947849,51.497683,6.7382846,6.746241' lat='51.49646145' 
lon='6.74226302912559' display_name='Warmbandwerk 1, Kaiser-Wilhelm-Straße, 
ThyssenKrupp Steel Europe AG, Hamborn, Duisburg, Regierungsbezirk Düsseldorf, 
Nordrhein-Westfalen, 47166, Deutschland' class='building' type='yes' 
importance='0.101'>@3:394 in java.io.InputStreamReader@dccfe0c)
```

The XML Document:

```
<searchresults timestamp="Sat, 05 Nov 16 00:09:25 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="warmbandwerk" polygon="false" exclude_place_ids="129799074,151481629" more_url="http://ip-10-98-168-38.mq-us-east-1.ec2.aolcloud.net:8000/nominatim/v1/search?format=xml&exclude_place_ids=129799074,151481629&accept-language=de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3&q=warmbandwerk">

    <place 
     place_id="129799074" 
     osm_type="way" 
     osm_id="220625788" 
     place_rank="30" 
     boundingbox="51.4947849,51.497683,6.7382846,6.746241"     
     lat="51.49646145" 
     lon="6.74226302912559" 
     display_name="Warmbandwerk 1, Kaiser-Wilhelm-Straße, ThyssenKrupp Steel Europe AG, Hamborn, Duisburg, Regierungsbezirk Düsseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 47166, Deutschland" 
     class="building" 
     type="yes" 
     importance="0.101"/>

    <place 
     place_id="151481629"
     osm_type="relation" 
     osm_id="2917388" 
     place_rank="30" 
     boundingbox="51.4860521,51.4891516,6.7050164,6.7144352" 
     lat="51.48741265" 
     lon="6.70882226405504" 
     display_name="Warmbandwerk 2, Werkstraße 1, ThyssenKrupp Steel Europe AG, Beeckerwerth, Meiderich/Beeck, Duisburg, Regierungsbezirk Düsseldorf, Nordrhein-Westfalen, 47139, Deutschland" 
     class="building" 
     type="yes" 
     importance="0.101"/>

</searchresults>
```

My MainActivity. Its not the whole activity. Only the segments relevant to the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

...

public void myClickHandler(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_search_string);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        String link = getResources().getString(R.string.link);
        String stringUrl = link + message;
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadXmlTask().execute(stringUrl);
        } else {
            // show error
        }
    }

private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
        textView.setTextSize(16);
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}

private String loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    XMLParser XMLParser = new XMLParser();
    List<XMLParser.Entry> entries = null;

    StringBuilder htmlString = new StringBuilder();
    htmlString.append("<h3>" + getResources().getString(R.string.page_title) + "</h3>");
    htmlString.append("<em>" + getResources().getString(R.string.updated));

    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        entries = XMLParser.parse(stream);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    for (XMLParser.Entry entry : entries) {
        htmlString.append("<p><a href='");
        htmlString.append(entry.longitude);
        htmlString.append(entry.latitude);
        htmlString.append(entry.place_id);
    }

    return htmlString.toString();
}

private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    return conn.getInputStream();
}

...

}
```

My XML Parser Class:

```
public class XMLParser {
private static final String ns = null;

public List parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}


private List readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List entries = new ArrayList();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "searchresults");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("place")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

public static class Entry {
    public final String longitude;
    public final String latitude;
    public final String place_id;

    private Entry(String lon, String lat, String place_id) {
        this.longitude = lon;
        this.latitude = lat;
        this.place_id = place_id;
    }
}

private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "searchresults");
    String lon = null;
    String lat = null;
    String place_id = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("place")) {
            lon = readLongitude(parser);
            lat = readLatitude(parser);
            place_id = readPlace_id(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Entry(lon, lat, place_id);
}

private String readLongitude(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "place");
    String longitude = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "lon");
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "place");
    return longitude;

}

private String readLatitude(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "place");
    String latitude = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "lat");
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "place");
    return latitude;
}

private String readPlace_id(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "place");
    String place_id = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "place_id");
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "place");
    return place_id;
}

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you include the code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
a the top of the xml file?

Comment: @JacksonSiro Yes. the xml file originates from the nominatim servers. I send a query to them in my code and get back the file.